# Поиск кратчайших путей в графе

Tags: python, функциональное-программирование

Есть список рёбер и список смежности вершин. Хочу написать алгоритм поиска кратчайших путей в графе. Дейкстры, Беллмана-Форда - без разницы. Но написать надо в функциональном стиле. Никак не могу это сделать, только в императивном могу. Может быть кто-то знает или есть готовые реализации? (python)

Answer (score 0):

Взято из этого [источника](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

```
def Dijkstra(N, S, matrix):
    valid = [True]*N        
    weight = [1000000]*N
    weight[S] = 0
    for i in range(N):
        min_weight = 1000001
        ID_min_weight = -1
        for j in range(N):
            if valid[j] and weight[j] < min_weight:
                min_weight = weight[j]
                ID_min_weight = j
        for z in range(N):
            if weight[ID_min_weight] + matrix[ID_min_weight][z] < weight[z]:
                weight[z] = weight[ID_min_weight] + matrix[ID_min_weight][z]
        valid[ID_min_weight] = False
    return weight
```

- N — количество вершин;
- S — номер стартовой вершины (отсчитывая от нуля);
- matrix — матрица смежности исходного графа, где несуществующие рёбра имеют бесконечный вес;
- В данном случае бесконечность равна 1000000;

Comment: Это явно не функциональный стиль, а обычный императивный